# mySql Selection failed "Database selection failed" using easyphp

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just started programming in php and would like to ask a question about the database selection code for mysql in the php coding. 
I used phpmyadmin to create a database "admin" when in phpmyadmin I click on privileges and see the name as"admin@127.0.0.1". I created a connection to the database using this code in PHP:

```
<?php $connection = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "admin", "admin123");
if (!$connection)   


die("Database connection failed:" . mysqli_error());
```

and now i want to select the tables in the database I use this command:

```
     $selected = mysqli_select_db("admin", $connection);
    if (!$selected) 

    {
            die('Database selection failed:' .mysqli_error());
    }

?>
```

I know it connects because when only using the connection command when opening my broswer I can see the header i put in html, but I get an error with the selection command and cannot continue.

```
Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\databaZE.php on line 6##

Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\databaZE.php on line 8
Database selection failed:
```

Firstly is there a problem with the way I wrote my database name thats why it cannot connect and giving me error msg's?I used 127.0.0.1 as database, admin@127.0.0.1 but still same msg. I tried both mysql and mysqli but it doesnt seem to work also.

Edit: first time user sorry am a little confused with inputting code.

Comment: The error message is rather self-explainatory: `Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli`. Paramater 1 should be an mysqli object, you gave a string: `admin`. Next time just look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) first....

Comment: thaks for the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have them the wrong way around,

```
$selected = mysqli_select_db("admin", $connection);
```

should be

```
$selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, "admin");
```

And

```
die('Database selection failed:' .mysqli_error());
```

should be

```
die('Database selection failed:' .mysqli_error($connection));
```

Comment: Guess what? it works thanks I guess I was watching some old videos cause they use mysql and not mysqli and put the $connection last and admin first but when I switch them like u said it works. Thank you.